# Meaning of "so that the weight of destiny no longer bore on the current problems of my life"

Tags: sentence-meaning, interpretation

> At night I lay awake looking at the darkness, listening to the silence,
> prefiguring the future, picking out of the past the scraps I had overlooked,
> those rejected events which now came to the foreground, large and
> important, **so that the weight of destiny no longer bore on the current
> problems of my life**, whatever they were at the time (for who lives without
> problems every day? Why waste the nights on them?).

I looked up the meaning of "bear on" in the dictionary but then again I want be sure about my understanding.

bear on something means: to relate to or possibly influence something

so can we say the sentence in bold means: she no longer believed in destiny and she thought her problems didn't caused by destiny?

source: A Far Cry From kensington by Muriel Spark

Answer (score 2):

The writer was thinking about the future, and then started to think about the past and forgot about her current problems concerning the future

> so that the weight of destiny no longer bore on the current problems of my life,

The weight = the pressure that I felt

of destiny = caused by [thinking about] the future

No longer bore = no longer pressed down (to bear *transitive* = to carry; to bear *intransitive* [+ (adverb or adverbial phrase)] = to press down[1]

on he current problems of my life (I think you understood this.]

[1]OED

> **IV. To push, thrust, press, and extended uses. To exert pressure on, and related senses.**
>
> **25.a. intransitive. Of a (literal or figurative) weight or load: to press down on or upon (a person or thing); to weigh on.**
>
> 1829   R. Southey All for Love vi. 63   *While she pray'd the load of care Less heavily bore on her heart.*
>
> 1996   Courier Mail (Queensland) (Nexis) 3 Aug. 21   *The weight of responsibility bears heavily on his shoulders.*